# Disable network manager for a particular interface

Tags: linux, networking, configuration-files, configure

I would like to disable network manager service for particular interface(s). "/etc/init.d/NetworkManager stop" is not going to serve my purpose since will stop the service. Please let me know how to achieve this. Please suggest commands/code only - I am not interested in graphical configuration. If there is some rpm/patch available already please refer it to me. Can we configure network manager in such a way so that it will not detect any new network card plugged into the system?

Thanks in advance,

Souvik

Comment: Is it possible to disable network manager for wireless network? Or can I configure the system so that network manager does not get notified when a new card is plugged in?

Comment: If I uncheck the wireless network checkbox from the network manager icon, then also network manager scans for available APs once I plugged the card in which is creating trouble for me.

Comment: Is there any kernel flags which can control network manager operations?

Comment: In Ubuntu 14.10 and before, NetworkManager correctly ignored interfaces created by VirtualBox (vboxnet*). In 15.04 it insists on managing them and solutions here do not work. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1485558 . In the meantime, any solution working on 15.04 would be nice!

Answer (score 28):

Put this in your NetworkManager.conf (usually at /etc/NetworkManager/):

```
[main]
plugins=keyfile

[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=mac:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

of course, adjust the mac address to the device your want to ignore.

Comment: note that the file should sometimes be located at /etc/NetworkManager/nm-system-settings.conf , depending on your distribution

Comment: Didn't work for me on Gentoo using Systemd and NetworkManager 1.0.6, any ideas?

Comment: You can also ignore device by name using `unmanaged-devices=interface-name:vboxnet0` etc.

Comment: @aliopi add multiple interfaces separated by commas. Example:  `unmanaged-devices=interface-name:vmnet8,interface-name:vmnet1,interface-name:vmnet2,interface-name:vmnet0`

Answer (score 10):

I realise this question is a bit old, but it came up when I was trying to Google the answer to this myself. What eventually worked for me was:

1. Add the interface to `/etc/network/interfaces`. For mine:

```
    iface eth1 inet static
        address 192.168.168.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.168.1
```

1. Restart networking: `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`
2. Restart Network Manager: `sudo service network-manager restart`

Network Manager should ignore any interfaces it finds in `/etc/network/interfaces`. At this point obviously you're on your own for managing this interface with `ifconfig` or something similar.

Comment: If network manager is using _ifupdown_ plugin, the `NetworkManager.conf` file should have `managed=False` in `[ifupdown]` section.

Answer (score 10):

NetworkManager will **not** attempt to control a given interface if you set the interface to `unmanaged` using the `nmcli` command.

```
nmcli dev set wlp2s0 managed no
```

You can verify the interface is no longer managed with the following:

```
nmcli dev status
```

Output example:

```
DEVICE             TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION      
wlp2s0             wifi      unmanaged     --
```

Comment: The interface will be managed again by networkmanager after reboot

Answer (score 2):

On my RHEL 6.5 system, I had to edit the configuration file for the particular adapter (/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0) and add the following line:

NM_CONTROLLED=no

The 2nd part of your question, "Can we configure network manager in such a way so that it will not detect any new network card plugged into the system?", I think is handled in the /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf file with the line:

no-auto-default=00:80:A4:0A:3C:20,

Set this property of course to the value of the MAC address for your adapter.
More info on this option can be read [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/NetworkManager.conf.5.html).